# How to use append filter on array (Shopify)

Tags: shopify, liquid

Hi there i added on footer section a list of policies (shop.policies) with an output like:

```
Privacy Policy Terms of service
```

Then i added append filter append on array, like:

```
{{ policy.title | append: ' /' }}
```

with an output:

```
Privacy Policy / Terms of service /
```

How can i remove the last ' /' on that string?

Thanks in advance community

EDITED:

added part of code where it is needed.

```
<ul class="list list-policies">
            {%- for policy in shop.policies %}
              <a 
                href="{{ policy.url }}"
                rel="noopener noreferrer"
                class="text-xs tracking-tighter uppercase font-bold" 
                title="{{ policy.title }}"
              >
                {{ policy.title | append: ' /' | remove_last: '/' }}
              </a>
            {%- endfor %}
          </ul>
```

Comment: use like this `{{ policy.title | append: ' /' | remove_last: '/'}}`

Comment: @Onkar i tried it, but remove all "/" cause there are 2 strings on that array suposed, so the output of it is: Privacy policy Terms of service

Comment: you need to post the full code for better understanding of flow, one liner is not much expressive.

Comment: @Onkar i added full code if it helps, thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, thanks for sharing the full code, it loop the array and append and remove the '/' same time.

You need to check the loop and then add the '/'

```
<ul class="list list-policies">
  {%- for policy in shop.policies %}
    <a 
      href="{{ policy.url }}"
      rel="noopener noreferrer"
      class="text-xs tracking-tighter uppercase font-bold" 
      title="{{ policy.title }}"
    >
      {{ policy.title }}{% unless forloop.last %} / {% endunless %}
    </a>
  {%- endfor %}
</ul>
```

You need to check the `forloop` `last` using the `forloop.last` and if not last then append the '/' after the title.

You can also read more the [forloop](https://shopify.dev/api/liquid/objects#forloop) here